# campos duplicados usando while

Tags: sql-server

buenas necesito insertar unas xml en una tabla y al hacer el while para la inserción de uno a cada campo se me duplican los valores deberían ser 37 y se insertan 37 veces los 37 registros

```
select @count=count(*)FROM @TABLA

while @id<=@count
begin
    insert into Let_XML2 
    SELECT (select * from (select  piev_Id, tsecodigo,  piev_escomunidad, piev_NumFactura, piev_TotalNeto, piev_IVA, piev_rutVendedor, piev_dvVendedor, piev_nomvendedor, piev_apePatVendedor, 
                      piev_apeMatVendedor, piev_calidadVendedor, piev_codigoPostalVendedor, piev_comunaVendedor, piev_direccionVendedor, piev_nroDireccionVendedor, 
                      piev_telefonoVendedor, piev_perCorreoVendedor, piev_rutComprador, piev_dvComprador, piev_nomComprador, piev_apePatComprador, piev_apeMatcomprador, 
                      piev_calidadComprador, piev_comunacomprador, piev_direccionComprador, piev_nroDireccionComprador, piev_codigoPostalComprador, piev_telefonoComprador, 
                      piev_perCorreoComprador, piev_CIT, piev_CodMotor, piev_Chasis, piev_Marca, piev_Modelo, piev_AnioVeh, piev_tveglosa, piev_tveCodigo, piev_rutCompraPara, 
                      piev_dvCompraPara, piev_nomCompraPara, piev_apePatCompraPara, piev_apeMatCompraPara, piev_comunaCompraPara, piev_direccionCompraPara, 
                      piev_codigoPostalCompraPara, piev_telefonoCompraPara, piev_calidadCompraPara, piev_nroDireccionCompraPara, piev_perCorreoCompraPara, piev_CodLlaves, 
                      piev_vin, piev_cid, piev_carga, piev_tipoCarga, piev_nroejes, piev_nroSerie, piev_cantidadAsientos, piev_cantidadPuertas, piev_valorimpuesto, 
                      piev_tipoDocumento, piev_moneda, piev_terminacionesPpu, piev_tipologia, piev_PesoVehiculoKG, piev_tipoPesoBruto, piev_tipoCarroceria, piev_otraCarroceria, 
                      piev_tipoPotencia, piev_Potencia, piev_tipoTraccion, piev_nroSolRepertorio, piev_fechaRepertorio, piev_ppuReingreso, piev_fechaResolucionExterna, 
                      piev_TipoCombustible, piev_ColorVehiculo, piev_colCodigo, piev_regionVendedor, piev_regionComprador, piev_regionCompraPara, piev_tipoSpiev, ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY tsecodigo ASC)AS RANK from @TABLA) as ji where rank=@id FOR XML RAW ('CREAR_SIPIVE'), ELEMENTS)--, XMLSCHEMA ('urn:example.com')   
    ,piev_Id
    ,tsecodigo
    ,getdate() from @tabla
    SELECT @id = @id+1
end
```

¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: no deberías tener el `while` dentro del bloque `begin-end`?

Comment: ahí están......

Comment: el `while` no lo tenes dentro del bloque `begin-end`

Comment: además que significa `SELECT @id = @id+1`? no será `SET @id = @id+1`? quizá ese sea el problema, que no se te actualiza la variable `@id`

Comment: nada probe ambos

Comment: pasa que no se hacer ese tipo de inserción así de a grupo, entre otras cosas, pero si se insertan 37 veces yo le sacaría el `while` y ahí se debería insertar una sola vez los 37 registros, no?

Answer (score 0):

Primero, estas haciendo que el while recorra x veces el número de registros en @TABLA

Segundo, al hacer la instrucción **insert-select**, estas seleccionando todos los registros de @TABLA ya que no los estas filtrando.

Recomendación:

Si en una iteración te inserta todos los registros requeridos, entonces lo mejor sería eliminar la instrucción while, quedando de la siguiente manera

```
insert into Let_XML2 
    SELECT (select * from (select  piev_Id, tsecodigo,  piev_escomunidad, piev_NumFactura, piev_TotalNeto, piev_IVA, piev_rutVendedor, piev_dvVendedor, piev_nomvendedor, piev_apePatVendedor, 
                      piev_apeMatVendedor, piev_calidadVendedor, piev_codigoPostalVendedor, piev_comunaVendedor, piev_direccionVendedor, piev_nroDireccionVendedor, 
                      piev_telefonoVendedor, piev_perCorreoVendedor, piev_rutComprador, piev_dvComprador, piev_nomComprador, piev_apePatComprador, piev_apeMatcomprador, 
                      piev_calidadComprador, piev_comunacomprador, piev_direccionComprador, piev_nroDireccionComprador, piev_codigoPostalComprador, piev_telefonoComprador, 
                      piev_perCorreoComprador, piev_CIT, piev_CodMotor, piev_Chasis, piev_Marca, piev_Modelo, piev_AnioVeh, piev_tveglosa, piev_tveCodigo, piev_rutCompraPara, 
                      piev_dvCompraPara, piev_nomCompraPara, piev_apePatCompraPara, piev_apeMatCompraPara, piev_comunaCompraPara, piev_direccionCompraPara, 
                      piev_codigoPostalCompraPara, piev_telefonoCompraPara, piev_calidadCompraPara, piev_nroDireccionCompraPara, piev_perCorreoCompraPara, piev_CodLlaves, 
                      piev_vin, piev_cid, piev_carga, piev_tipoCarga, piev_nroejes, piev_nroSerie, piev_cantidadAsientos, piev_cantidadPuertas, piev_valorimpuesto, 
                      piev_tipoDocumento, piev_moneda, piev_terminacionesPpu, piev_tipologia, piev_PesoVehiculoKG, piev_tipoPesoBruto, piev_tipoCarroceria, piev_otraCarroceria, 
                      piev_tipoPotencia, piev_Potencia, piev_tipoTraccion, piev_nroSolRepertorio, piev_fechaRepertorio, piev_ppuReingreso, piev_fechaResolucionExterna, 
                      piev_TipoCombustible, piev_ColorVehiculo, piev_colCodigo, piev_regionVendedor, piev_regionComprador, piev_regionCompraPara, piev_tipoSpiev, ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY tsecodigo ASC)AS RANK from @TABLA) as ji where rank=@id FOR XML RAW ('CREAR_SIPIVE'), ELEMENTS)--, XMLSCHEMA ('urn:example.com')   
    ,piev_Id
    ,tsecodigo
    ,getdate() from @tabla
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que necesito agregar los xml que genera el while a la  tabla Let_Xml. El while me genera un xml por cada registro y debo guardar esos sí lo saco del while me genera un xml con todos los registros de la @tabla

Answer (score 0):

si lo saco del while y agrego el resultado del while a una variable cuando hago el insert en la columna xml_Request solo se inserta el ultimo valor que tomo @A
y necesito el valor de cada fila que genera el while

```
declare @xml table (XmlSpiev xml)
declare @A as xml


while @id<=@count
begin

   set @A =  (select * from (select  piev_Id, tsecodigo,  piev_escomunidad, piev_NumFactura, piev_TotalNeto, piev_IVA, piev_rutVendedor, piev_dvVendedor, piev_nomvendedor, piev_apePatVendedor, 
                      piev_apeMatVendedor, piev_calidadVendedor, piev_codigoPostalVendedor, piev_comunaVendedor, piev_direccionVendedor, piev_nroDireccionVendedor, 
                      piev_telefonoVendedor, piev_perCorreoVendedor, piev_rutComprador, piev_dvComprador, piev_nomComprador, piev_apePatComprador, piev_apeMatcomprador, 
                      piev_calidadComprador, piev_comunacomprador, piev_direccionComprador, piev_nroDireccionComprador, piev_codigoPostalComprador, piev_telefonoComprador, 
                      piev_perCorreoComprador, piev_CIT, piev_CodMotor, piev_Chasis, piev_Marca, piev_Modelo, piev_AnioVeh, piev_tveglosa, piev_tveCodigo, piev_rutCompraPara, 
                      piev_dvCompraPara, piev_nomCompraPara, piev_apePatCompraPara, piev_apeMatCompraPara, piev_comunaCompraPara, piev_direccionCompraPara, 
                      piev_codigoPostalCompraPara, piev_telefonoCompraPara, piev_calidadCompraPara, piev_nroDireccionCompraPara, piev_perCorreoCompraPara, piev_CodLlaves, 
                      piev_vin, piev_cid, piev_carga, piev_tipoCarga, piev_nroejes, piev_nroSerie, piev_cantidadAsientos, piev_cantidadPuertas, piev_valorimpuesto, 
                      piev_tipoDocumento, piev_moneda, piev_terminacionesPpu, piev_tipologia, piev_PesoVehiculoKG, piev_tipoPesoBruto, piev_tipoCarroceria, piev_otraCarroceria, 
                      piev_tipoPotencia, piev_Potencia, piev_tipoTraccion, piev_nroSolRepertorio, piev_fechaRepertorio, piev_ppuReingreso, piev_fechaResolucionExterna, 
                      piev_TipoCombustible, piev_ColorVehiculo, piev_colCodigo, piev_regionVendedor, piev_regionComprador, piev_regionCompraPara, piev_tipoSpiev, ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY tsecodigo ASC)AS RANK from @TABLA) as ji where rank=@id FOR XML RAW ('CREAR_SIPIVE'), ELEMENTS)--, XMLSCHEMA ('urn:example.com')   

 SELECT @id = @id+1
end
--insert into Let_XML(xml_Request) values (@A)
insert into Let_XML 
select @A
    ,piev_Id
    ,tsecodigo
    ,getdate() from @tabla
select * from Let_XML
```